# Iterating through code to add a new line on the nth term

Tags: c

How would I go about adding a new line on the 10th term on this zybooks question

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
   
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\t", n);
   
    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
        else {
            n = n / 2;
        }
 
        printf("%d\t",n);
    }
   
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by counting the iterations. When that reaches 10, output a newline and reset the count.

Comment: I''d guess that then entire purpose of that question is to get **YOU** to figure out how to do it, so that you can use what you've learned so far to find the answer. If we do it for you, the only thing you learn is how to copy and paste the work of others. Make an effort to figure it out yourself. It's a relatively simple solution if you just think about it for a minute - try doing that instead of trying to take a shortcut and learning nothing useful in the process. This is very similar to the hundreds of *do my homework for me* questions that are closed here every day for lack of effort.

Comment: The "Collatz Conjecture"... Have some **real** fun changing `(n>1)` to `(n>=1)`... "To infinity and beyond" ... `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a counter variable `i` which increments until 10 is reached. Once it is reached a newline character (`\n`) is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    int n, i = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n); 

    printf("%d\t", n);

    while (n > 1) { 

           i++;

           (n % 2 == 1) ? (n = 3*n+1) : (n = n/2);

           if (i == 10) {
               i = 0;
               printf("\n");
           }
           else {  
               printf("%d\t", n);
           }
    } 

    printf("\n");

    return 0; 
}
```